# Recover standard out from a failed Hadoop job

Tags: streaming, hadoop

I'm running a large Hadoop streaming job where I process a large list of files with each file being processed as a single unit. To do this, my input to my streaming job is a single file with a list of all the file names on separate lines.

In general, this works well. However, I ran into an issue where I was partially through a large job (~36%) when Hadoop ran into some files with issues and for some reason it seemed to crash the entire job. If the job had completed successfully, what would have been printed to standard out would be a line for each file as it was completed along with some stats from my program that's processing each file. However, with this failed job, when I try to look at the output that would have been sent to standard out, it is empty. I know that roughly 36% of the files were processed (because I'm saving the data to a database), but it's not easy for me to generate a list of which files were successfully processed and which ones remain. Is there anyway to recover this logging to standard out?

One thing I can do is look at all of the log files for the completed/failed tasks, but this seems more difficult to me and I'm not sure how to go about retrieving the good/bad list of files this way.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hadoop captures system.out data here :**

/mnt/hadoop/logs/userlogs/task_id

**However, I've found this unreliable, and Hadoop jobs dont usually use standard out for debugging, rather - the convetion is to use counters.**

For each of your documents, you can summarize document characteristics : like length, number of normal ascii chars, number of new lines.

Then, you can have 2 counters: a counter for "good" files, and a counter for "bad" files.

It probably be pretty easy to note that the bad files have something in common [no data, too much data, or maybe some non printable chars].

Finally, you obviously will have to look at the results after the job is done running.

The problem, of course, with system.out statements is that the jobs running on various machines can't integrate their data.  Counters get around this problem - they are easily integrated into a clear and accurate picture of the overall job.

Of course, the problem with counters is the information content is entirely numeric, but, with a little creativity, you can easily find ways to quantitatively describe the data in a meaningfull way.

**WORST CASE SCENARIO : YOU REALLY NEED TEXT DEBUGGING, and you dont want it in a temp file**

In this case, you can use MultipleOutputs to write out ancillary files with other data in them.  You can emit records to these files in the same way as you would for the part-r-0000* data.

In the end, I think you will find that, ironically, the restriction of having to use counters will increase the readability of your jobs : it is pretty intuitive, once you think about it, to debug using numerical counts rather than raw text --- i find, quite often that much of my debugging print statements are, when cut down to their raw information content,  are basically just counters...

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm going to look more into counters and see if I can use that to solve my problem.

Comment: Counters definitely solve my problem. However, I haven't been able to find a good solution on the web for how to access the counters in an easy to parse text format after a job has completed. I can see the counters on the jobtracker:50030 webpage, but I don't know where to find them in a text file. Any ideas?